# Error in calling Stanford sentiment parser in Syuzhet R package

Tags: r, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

I tried to call the Stanford sentiment analyzer from Syuzhet R package.  I followed the instructions in the reference manual and vignettes from the Cran site. I installed the Stanford CoreNLP package on my machine and it works fine standalone. However, when I called the Stanford sentiment analyzer from R, I got the following error:
***Error in system(cmd, input = text_vector, intern = TRUE, ignore.stderr = TRUE) : 'cd' not found*.**
 I searched the web, but couldn't find a solution. Here is my code:

```
library(syuzhet)
test <- c("I am a very happy person.", "I am a very sad person.")
tagger_path <-  "C:/Users/sqchen/Documents/R/stanford-corenlp-full-2015-12-09"
stanford_vector <- get_sentiment(test, method="stanford", tagger_path)
```

Calling an alternative method *get_stanford_sentiment* gave the some error. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: `cd` is a UNIX command to change the directory. I assume the package is trying to change directory to the `tagger_path` and can't find the command `cd`. Either you are not on a UNIX machine, or your path does not include the folder where `cd` is to be found.

Comment: Hi Gopala, thanks for your reply. You are right. I'm using Windows.  Is there any workaround to make it work on Windows?

Comment: Actually - its been ages since I used Windows. It may also have `cd` command, but path may be a problem. Check windows path.

Comment: I had similar problems on a windows machine and wrapped things up in my own wrapper package on GitHub: https://github.com/trinker/stansent  Give it a try.  Feedback appreciated.

Comment: Hi Tyler, your wrapper works! Please add the following to the installation instruction: pacman::p_load_gh(c("trinker/textshape", "trinker/parsent")). Thanks for solving my problem!